# How to break a long text in react typescript

Tags: react-typescript

I am new into typescript react and frontend development. All I need to do is break the text inside of the content into 2 line. I looked online and found few solutions to add `\n` to the text of the context, but they didn't work for me. Could someone give me some hit. Thank you

```
 <text>
    {content} \\{content} returns some thing like: "This is very long text please break from here\n in order to make it more readable"
  </text>
```

Comment: @ytan11 adding \n to the context content and doing css does not work for me

Comment: Did you tried `white-space: pre-line` style, using the `pre` tag, or `&NewLine;` entity provided in the answers from the link above?

Comment: Possibly covered by "[How to prevent long words from breaking my div?](/q/320184/90527)", and likely many other questions on SO.

Comment: What is the overall goal? Currently, this question suffers from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133817).

Answer (score 0):

Please style the text

```
.text{
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vh;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

[image]